# Angular - Failing to intercept http requests using a http service

Tags: angular

I have an angular 6 application.

I am assigning a HTTP interceptor to a specific lazy loaded module. When i make http calls directly in the component using http client, the requests are intercepted. However, making http calls via a core module service, it will fail to intercept these http requests.

See the following example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckzdvx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fa%2Ffirst%2Ffirst.component.ts

first.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiService } from './../../core/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first',
  templateUrl: './first.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first.component.css']
})
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  call() {
    this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
  }

  call2() {

    this.apiService.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);

    });

  }

}
```

**Use case**

I am making 2 calls, the first `call()` is intercepted, the second `call2()` is not being intercepted.

**Outcome**

`call2()` should be intercepted whilst using the api service.

It's important that the http interceptor is declared only in the module it is needed in. As i don't want other modules to have their HTTP requests intercepted.

Comment: probaly apiservice is using different HTTPclient without interceptors.

Comment: Yes but why? and what is the solution here :)

Comment: Didnt see the code. Isnt Swilkos answer sufficient?

Comment: No it is not sufficient because, i only want to declare the interceptor in a specific module. I don't want other modules to be intercepted, if i declare it in the app.module.ts all modules using http requests are going to be intercepted. Please refer to the stackblitz for the code.

Comment: So what is required outcome? - this is totally unclear - use specific module names etc

Comment: The outcome is that call2 should be intercepted.

Comment: Please edit your question as it clearly states that curent behavior is just like this.

Comment: If you read it all, i did already mention it at the very bottom it says "It's important that the http interceptor is declared only in the module it is needed in. As i don't want other modules to have their HTTP requests intercepted."

Comment: You have **described current behavior as** *am making 2 calls, the first call() is intercepted, the second call2() is not being intercepted*. Dont force people here to either deep analisys what  you have wrote nor to read between the lines. If I am saying that it is confusing (and 2 other answers confirms that) than it is and you have to change that.

Comment: As for getting back to the "question" it either cannot be done, or you will have provide another service in module B. Interceptors cannot be changed on runtime so Angular would have to create service instance using http client with interceptors provided in B.

Comment: There was a question about modyfing interceptors on runtime and I have stated it is not possible, however it would be possible if you would write interceptor that contains "child" interceptors and that you could modify on runtime. That was accepted. Maybe similar solution would help you out.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean now. I am not trying to provide any intercepts to module B. module A should only have http requests intercepted which should work with my api service.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the child interceptors solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if its possible to do what you required out of the box, but when I had similar issue (had to intercept calls made by all services/modules except one) I wrote interceptor that inspects request headers and react to it. I had special header "skip-app-id" added to "no intercepting requests" that triggers request interception bypass in interceptor itself

So basicly, interceptor skipped intercepting if request contained "trigger" header. You could do the similar approach and add special controll header to intercepted requests to trigger interception, and bypass it otherwise.

Wrapping it up, in general it would be like this:

1. Provide global interceptor (as it is the easiest way and you got it alreade)
2. Make it header sensitive - interceptor must inspect request headers
3. If request contains specified header - lets say "do-intercept:true" do interception work
4. Remove "do-intercept:true" header from the request, as we dont want to send it anywhere
5. If no triggering header - skip interception logic (short circuit)

More or less witll do exactly what you have required.

Comment: I could see this work, in fact ive already tested this. I just thought it was a hastle to add an extra header to all the other HTTP requests i don't want intercepted.

Comment: You can either add header to trigger interception (default off/nothing is intercepted) or to bypass it (default on/intercepts all). The choice is yours.

Comment: The other option is to use HttpBackend for other requests instead of HttpClient.

Comment: From your description it seams that default-off is the way to go. Anyway, you got the point.

Comment: yeah i'll keep this in mind but will leave it open to see if anyone comes up with a different solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add the following provider to your `app.module.ts` to hit all requests

```
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from 
'@angular/common/http';

import { MyInterceptor} from './my.interceptor';

@NgModule({
 imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, AppRoutingModule,
 CoreModule.forRoot(),
 HttpClientModule],
 declarations: [AppComponent],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent],
 providers: [
 {
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: MyInterceptor,
  multi: true
 }
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Please read the last sentence of my post. I mentioned i want to declare the interceptor in a specific module so other modules are not intercepted. If i declare it in the app.module.ts it is doing exactly opposite of what i want.

Answer (score -1):

The reason `call2()` is not hitting your interceptor is: it is not using `FirstComponent`'s injected `HttpClient`. It is using `ApiService` instead. That instance of `ApiService` has its own `HttpClient` injected in the constructor and **that** `HttpClient` doesn't provide `MyInterceptor` as an `HTTP_INTERCEPTOR`.

Changing that second call to `this.http.get` will make it hit your interceptor.

Comment: I want to use the api service though, thats the whole point. So i need it to be intercepted whilst using the api service.

Comment: You **probably** should have mentioned that in the original version of the question. You asked why it wasn't being intercepted. I answered that question and explained how dependency injection works and why your call wasn't being intercepted.

Comment: I assumed it was clear in the question title that im trying to use interceptor with a http service and if its failing i want it to work, not to just completely ignore the service....

Comment: No - you described what was happening and asked why. I explained why. Then you edited your question. It seems as though you want people to do your work for you and are downvoting people for literally answering your question. The solution @Antoniossss came up with is nice. There is discussion on this topic on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18155) and it seems as though most people are using a similar approach. However, [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18155#issuecomment-363822704) might be of interest to you.

Comment: and i never asked anyone to do the work for me. I spent time making that stackblitz so people could understand the question. So don't try to make that the case.